# Losing disks with LVM

Tags: lvm

I have a question:

We are setting up 5 new servers with 4 disks of 1 TB each.

We are planning of using LVM Mirror so we have protection over our data.

My question is, if I lose a disk, since we are using LVM mirror, are we still able to access the data normally until we replace the broken disk. And, in this scenario, out of the 20 disks, how many usable ones will I have?

Thanks

Robson

Answer (score 0):

For your question, yes, you will still be able to access the data normally even if a disk fails.

For your second question:

Out of the 4 disks (3 mirrors) you will be using to create the mirror, if you lose one disk, you will still have 2 mirrors (ie.3 disks) left.

Comment: In total, I will have 20 disks between the 5 servers. Got the point that I can lose 1 disk and still access the information. But since we will be doing replication and repeated data will be stored in the disks, how many "usable" disks will we have? On the point that data will be replicated and taking up space. So how many "usable" disks in that case?

Comment: Do you mean, what is the percentage of the total physical disk space which will show at the software level as being available?  I.e., there are 4TB physical disk space; how many TB of files can you put on the LVM mirror before you run out of space?  (I don't know the answer but I wanted to clarify the question.)